# Tengo un problema en el programa

Tags: c, dev-c++

estoy haciendo un programa que cuando pones el dia y el mes automaticamente te calcula cuantos dias pasaron de el primer dia del año al mes donde estas parado por ejemplo 3/2=34 dias + de 3 de febrero pero estoy dando muchas vueltas y el codigo me queda gigante y necesito una mano y se que tiene errores de synstaxis por eso pregunto le agradeceria las opiniones e explicaciones que me puedan sobre como poder mejor el programa para que cumpla la funcion correcta y una cosa que casi me olvido de comentar es que el usuario elige aleatoriamente cual es el mes por esa misma razon esta el print que esta junto al swicht pero por alguna razon no me tomaba ni los caculos si quiera de cada caso

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int a;
int meses1=31;
int meses2=59;
int meses3=89;
int meses4=119;
int meses5=149;
int meses6=179;
int meses7=210;
int meses8=241;
int meses9=271;
int meses10=302;
int meses11=332;
int meses12=363;
int f;
int l;

printf("Ingresa dia:");
scanf("%d", &a);

 printf("mes y año: 1-Enero, 2-Febrero, 3-Marzo, 4-Abril, 5-Mayo, 6-Junio, 7-Julio, 8-Agosto, 
 9-Septiembre, 10-Octubre, 11-Novienbre, 12-Diciembre \n");
 scanf("%d", &l);

 switch(a,l){
 case 1:
    f=a+meses1;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 2:
    f=a+meses1;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 3:
    f=a+meses2;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 4:
    f=a+meses2;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 5:
    f=a+meses3;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 6:
    f=a+meses3;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 7:
    f=a+meses4;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 8:
    f=a+meses4;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 9:
    f=a+meses5;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 10:
    f=a+meses5;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 11:
    f=a+meses6;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;

case 12:
    f=a+meses6;
    printf("dias", f);
    break;
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Opiniones y explicaciones:

- **Usa nombres autoexplicativos para las variables**: cuando se lee el nombre de una variable, dicho nombre nos debe dar una idea de cuál es su objetivo en el código, nombres como `a`, `f` y `l` no nos dicen nada.
- **Si múltiples variables se refieren a lo mismo, probablemente deban ser una formación<sup>1</sup>**: Tus variables `mesesXX` parecen referirse a la cantidad de días desde el primer día del año, con una formación queda más organizado:

  ```
  int dias_desde_inicio[] = {31, 59, 89, 119, 149, 179, 210, 241, 271, 302, 332, 363};
  ```

Tienes muchos más errores, pero parece que no quieres hablar de errores de sintaxis, así que aplicando los puntos anteriores tu código podría parecerse a:

```
int dia;
printf("Ingresa dia:");
scanf("%d", &dia);

int mes;
printf("mes y año: 1-Enero, 2-Febrero, 3-Marzo, 4-Abril, 5-Mayo, 6-Junio, 7-Julio, 8-Agosto, 9-Septiembre, 10-Octubre, 11-Novienbre, 12-Diciembre \n");
scanf("%d", &mes);

printf("Dias %d", dia + dias_desde_inicio[mes]);
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.